# Stack Exchange Data Explorer offline?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I attempted to visit the Data Explorer today and received this message:

> ERROR
>
> The requested URL could not be
>   retrieved
>
> While trying to retrieve the URL:
>   http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries
>
> The following error was encountered:
>
> Connection to 70.37.90.220 Failed The
>   system returned:
>
> ```
> (111) Connection refused The remote host or network may be down.
> ```
>
> Please try the request again.
>
> Your cache administrator is webmaster.

Does anyone else get this error?

Comment: There have apparently been some [fuzzy issues with Azure, causing intermittent outages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56719/is-odata-stackexchange-com-down-for-everyone-or-just-me). It's been [reported frequently over](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57284/sede-is-down-planned-or-unexpected) [the past few days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57430/odata-is-not-working-at-all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Down for everyone, according to

http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://odata.stackexchange.com

Comment: lol didn't know about that website thanks.

Comment: lately a few of us have seen incorrect results from dfeojm - sometimes reporting outage hours after the resource is restored.